# We've got at least 80 generic i.imgur.com image links that might break on May 15, 2023; should/could they be updated to i.stack.imgur.com?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Below the Math SE meta question [Imgur's "old, unused, and inactive content"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35685/284619)

> Imgur plans to change its Terms of Service on May 15, 2023. Part of this will be the removal of "old, unused, and inactive content".
>
> Many of the images on Stack Exchange have imgur links. What will happen to those?

a comment says:

> We have [1,970 generic imgur images](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3ai.imgur.com&searchOn=3) subject to this (i.e. which don't don't use SE's corporate stack interface stack.imgur.com).

Space Exploration has [80 posts](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3ai.imgur.com&searchOn=3) with generic `i.imgur.com` links, frequently excellent, well received answers.

**Question:** We've got at least 80 generic i.imgur.com image links that might break on May 15, 2023; should/could they be updated to i.stack.imgur.com? Is there a way to update or convert these without necessarily bumping all to the active queue (not that that would be a bad thing necessarily)

Comment: also asked in [astronomy](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/905/7982)

Comment: Worst case, it’s only 80 questions and 10-ish days so could bump 8/day without overwhelming the active queue.

Comment: @fyrepenguin it's certainly possible to [do it like that](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703/7982) and the benefit is that the editor can judge if it's worth doing it (appropriate image etc.) but I think there might be an option to have it done silently by a bot so that it doesn't affect the queue (not that that would be a bad thing)

Comment: Well … time is running out, and seeing that nothing has been said one way or another … should we go ahead and convert them over, even if it bumps a lot of questions?

Comment: It is now May the 16th

Comment: _(not that that would be a bad thing necessarily)_ lolololol

Comment: @RussellBorogove checking the link in my question, the "winner" (most posts with at-risk images) seems to be [Organic Marble](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ai.imgur.com+user%3A6944) with 20 "hits", I also see a few [from you](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ai.imgur.com+user%3A195) and one from [called2voyage](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ai.imgur.com+user%3A58) as well. So while it being May 16th may not be a bad thing, dead links in high quality answers probably is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that the deadline has expired, I think that we should manually edit any posts with links that still work - before they break too.

I'm not sure what to do about questions and answers with links that are already broken.

Comment: Perhaps the Wayback Machine has those images.